# request() function returns undefined values

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, web-scraping, cors, web-crawler

so I'm currently making a Google Chrome Extension that will notify me whenever a new grade gets posted to my University's gradebook for all of my classes, so currently I'm trying to iteratively crawl and scrape the URL's and compare it to the last iteration (...? advice on this would be appreciated!), and currently when I use the request() function, even with asynchronization, the function currently returns undefined for the response and body, and gives me this other weird thing for the error if I try to console.log all of those.

Here's the error I'm getting after that:

```
bundle.js:24 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'headers' of undefined
    at Request._callback (bundle.js:24)
    at self.callback (bundle.js:54273)
    at Request.EventEmitter.emit (bundle.js:95413)
    at Request.start (bundle.js:54842)
    at Request.end (bundle.js:55610)
    at end (bundle.js:54652)
    at bundle.js:54666
    at Item.run (bundle.js:103974)
    at drainQueue (bundle.js:103944)
```

And here's my code (changed the URL so you don't see my school's login URL):

```
var Crawler = require("simplecrawler"),
    url = require("url"),
    cheerio = require("cheerio"),
    request = require("request");

var initialURL = "https://www.fakeURL.com/";


var crawler = new Crawler(initialURL);

request("https://www.fakeURL.com/", {
    // The jar option isn't necessary for simplecrawler integration, but it's
    // the easiest way to have request remember the session cookie between this
    // request and the next
    jar: true,
    mode: 'no-cors'
}, function(error, response, body) {
    // Start by saving the cookies. We'll likely be assigned a session cookie
    // straight off the bat, and then the server will remember the fact that
    // this session is logged in as user "iamauser" after we've successfully
    // logged in

    crawler.cookies.addFromHeaders(response.headers["set-cookie"]);

    // We want to get the names and values of all relevant inputs on the page,
    // so that any CSRF tokens or similar things are included in the POST
    // request
    var $ = cheerio.load(body),
        formDefaults = {},
        // You should adapt these selectors so that they target the
        // appropriate form and inputs
        formAction = $("#login").attr("action"),
        loginInputs = $("input");

    // We loop over the input elements and extract their names and values so
    // that we can include them in the login POST request
    loginInputs.each(function(i, input) {
        var inputName = $(input).attr("name"),
            inputValue = $(input).val();

        formDefaults[inputName] = inputValue;
    });

    // Time for the login request!
    request.post(url.resolve(initialURL, formAction), {
        // We can't be sure that all of the input fields have a correct default
        // value. Maybe the user has to tick a checkbox or something similar in
        // order to log in. This is something you have to find this out manually
        // by logging in to the site in your browser and inspecting in the
        // network panel of your favorite dev tools what parameters are included
        // in the request.
        form: Object.assign(formDefaults, {
            username: "secretusername",
            password: "secretpassword"
        }),
        // We want to include the saved cookies from the last request in this
        // one as well
        jar: true
    }, function(error, response, body) {
        // That should do it! We're now ready to start the crawler
        crawler.interval = 10000 //600000 // 10 minutes
        crawler.maxConcurrency = 1; // 1 active check at a time
        crawler.maxDepth = 5;
        crawler.start();
    });
});

crawler.on("fetchcomplete", function(queueItem, responseBuffer, response) {
    console.log("Fetched", queueItem.url, responseBuffer.toString());
});

// crawler.interval = 600000 // 10 minutes
// crawler.maxConcurrency = 1; // 1 active check at a time
// crawler.maxDepth = 5;
//
// crawler.start();
```

One thing to note is I added the 'no-cors' mode to my request so I can stop having problems with CORS whenever I tested this, but is that possibly what's causing this issue?

Thanks!

EDIT: I'm using Browserify to use the require() stuff in the browser. I can't post the actual code from bundle.js because it is extremely long and won't fit in here. Just wanted to clarify that. Thanks!

EDIT2: Here is what I'm given when I try to do console.log(error):

```
Error: Invalid value for opts.mode
    at new module.exports (bundle.js:108605)
    at Object.http.request (bundle.js:108428)
    at Object.https.request (bundle.js:97056)
    at Request.start (bundle.js:54843)
    at Request.end (bundle.js:55613)
    at end (bundle.js:54655)
    at bundle.js:54669
    at Item.run (bundle.js:103977)
    at drainQueue (bundle.js:103947)
```

Comment: Try to figure out what the contents of `error` are, and check `response.status`.  It looks like there is "some error" in your http request.  Without further info that's about all I can say.

Comment: I tried checking error, but the issue is that it gives me this: Error: Invalid value for opts.mode (full trace in original post). And I can't check response.status because response is undefined.

Comment: @OmarBaradei So, did the answer help you finally?

Answer (score 0):

As James said, if you get an error, check the error by logging it to console or whatever method you like most to show debug info.

If you are getting `Cannot read property 'headers' of undefined` is, as you said, that `response` is undefined, so your first callback line will fail, because it tries to access `response.headers`.

The way to simple-debug here is to `console.log()` the error, before reaching the line with the problem (as it halts there), so you have to simply add `console.log(error);` as the first line of your callback.

**The way to go:**

Although you may fix the problems you see in your `console.log(error)`, this code is doomed because you are not checking if you received an error and assuming that the request filled successfully. A net connection is chaotic, and a request can fail for a lot of reasons, so before accessing `request.headers` you have to check if any error happened and log it (or show it to you client, retry the request after X seconds, whatever you like most).

*Tip*: If you have a callback with an error parameter, check it. Is there as the first parameter for a reason.

The code will look like this:

```
request("https://www.fakeURL.com/", {
    jar: true,
    mode: 'no-cors'
}, function(error, response, body) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        makeTheRequestAgainIn(5000); // Milliseconds
    } else {
        doWhateverWith(response, body);
    }
});
```

**The error:**

Simply you can't disable CORS in the browser. You can disable it in node.js, as is not a browser, that's why there's a option for that in the request module, but browsers have security measures for a reason. If they can be avoided then they make no sense.

In short: Yes, you are having problems with CORS if you don't have enabled in the server.

*Protip*: When dealing with JavaScript in the browser, is a good practice to have the developer tools open (F12), as you have, this way you had seen the CORS error automatically logged in the console (or whatever network error happens). Also, switching to the Network tab and checking the request headers, response and such is a good practice too.

**EDIT:** Just noticed the Chrome Extension thing (dang). Extensions are less limited, so is fine to do those calls, as you can read here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr

Also, checked the `request` npm module [source code](https://github.com/jhiesey/stream-http/blob/master/lib/request.js#L51) and do not have a `no-cors` value. I think that you mixed the [Request API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request) with the `request` module.

Comment: I tried to do console.log(error), and it gives me this:
Error: Invalid value for opts.mode (I'll post the full thing in the original post above because formatting is weird in comments).

Also, based off what you said about the CORS issue, does that mean that I will be unable to proceed with this project if I'm trying to crawl/scrape from my school's gradebook website? Is there nothing that can be done at all to accomplish what I'm trying to do? Thanks again.

Comment: @OmarBaradei Yep, that means that you cannot disable CORS on the browser. By the way, just noticed the "Chrome Extesion" thing. Thought that you were making a website or something. Extensions are not as limited as normal browsing, as you can check here, so you may be able to do what you want, as long as is an Extension: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr Simply remove the mode parameter, set the permissions in the manifest and do your call, but not forget to follow my guidelines in error handling. Error checking is a primary thing to do when developing, and you were skipping it.

Comment: @OmarBaradei Also, I checked the `request` npm module and it don't have any `no-cors` value for `mode` parameter. I guess you mixed info around the internet. If you use the `request` module (not the same as the Request API) you have to check for the proper options on it, here: https://github.com/request/request. If you check the proper line in the source code, you see that there's no "no-cors" option: https://github.com/jhiesey/stream-http/blob/master/lib/request.js#L51

Comment: Wow thank you so much for all the help! So, I was able to make significant progress, but after some research, I've realized that my university's login system is setup behind CAS. This is very confusing to me as to how to handle authenticating with CAS via a POST request. Do you have any advice on how to handle this, or possibly a code snippet example or something I could look at to get an idea? I'm very stuck right now on this part as if I try to use the /serviceValidate url in my post request, it gives me back an invalid request and says service and ticket parameters are both required.

Comment: So how I think the workfow works is this: I'm on the portal page, I click the login button, it takes me to my university's login page backed by CAS, the user puts in his ID and password, clicks submit, it validates with CAS server, goes back to the login with success or failure, and if success, it will take me back to the portal page (where my grades can be found) successfully logged in. Hopefully that helps give a better idea. Thanks again!

Comment: Simply you have to reproduce it via AJAX (Using request, as you already do). Open the Network tab, as I mentioned before, and copy each request. Notice how the table fills each time you do something (clicking the login button and such), with the data that the browser sent to the server. For example, when you put your user and password and click the send button, you will notice that a new line appears in the table. If you click on it you will see the URL, if is a POST or GET and if is a POST all the data posted.

Comment: @OmarBaradei Along with the above, read this: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/reference or watch this video if you don't like reading xD https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PwoT18tp6Hs

Comment: @OmarBaradei Also, if my answer helped you to fix the error you received, please, mark it as answered.

Comment: Don't forget that as a developer, having the right tools when developing is a good practice (talking about having the Network tab open when you want to analyze traffic)